# Proving $\{n^3\}$ doesn't converge

Tags: sequences-and-series

Not sure if there's a duplicate, but here's where I'm stuck.

I know it's a sequence if $\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n,m\geq N,|a_n−a_m|<\varepsilon $

So right now I have for $\varepsilon = 1$

$$|a_n - a_{n+1}| = |n^3 - (n+1)^3|$$

But then I'm stuck what to do from here

Comment: If a sequence converges, then it is bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remark: If you work by *contradiction method* and suppose that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty}n^3=L$ is a real number. Thus, by definition for all $\varepsilon \in {\bf R}^{+*}$, there exists $N\in {\bf N}$ such that $$|n^3-L|< \varepsilon,\quad n\geqslant N$$
Then, in *particular* take $\varepsilon:=1$ should works. That is, we have $$|n^3-L|<1,\quad n\geqslant N$$
Now, you need to see if this leads you to a *contradiction*. If the answer is "yes" then our assumptions it was not correct and then we conclude that $\{n^3\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ is a sequence does not convergent.